# Can't get through CSS masking

Tags: css, css-mask

I'm trying to use CSS masking but can't figure out why is not working with this png.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jean-chiementin/pen/MWGzNvQ)

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  mask-image: url(https://wp.agriturismo-bien-etre.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/zig_mask.png);
  mask-repeat: repeat;
  mask-mode: alpha;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use `-webkit-` as the feature is still not a standard one then use another hosting for your image to avoid CORS security issue (Related [imgur image not loading due to CORS policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394277/8620333))

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/zWgV96b/zig-mask.png);
  -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```