# CSS Masking svg image

Tags: html, css

I've been having troubles with masking a svg onto my html file. I would like to take the svg and basically recolour it, and thats it. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, so don't hesitate to call me dumb lol. Here's some code I wrote, if someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated <3

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="mask"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS File**

```
.mask{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-mask-image: url(testing.svg);
    mask-image: url(testing.svg);
}
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74028863/8620333

Comment: .svgs are coloured with the fill property, if your trying to make it red you should try adding `fill: red;` to your css selector